# Cannot get my polyline drawn or visible

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I try to draw a polyline according to this example: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geometry-encodings.

My map is displayed, markers are displayed as well but the polyline is not drawn, or not visible.
I don't see what's wrong.

My javascript is:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=geometry"></script>

$( document ).ready(function($) {

    var map;
    var poly;
    var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
    var ndgIconBase = 'http://example.com/img/';
    var clickMarker;

    nextWaypoint = parseInt(document.getElementById('agpoiwaypoints_size').innerHTML, 10);
    countWaypoint = nextWaypoint;

    function initialize() {

        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');

        var content;
        content = document.getElementById('agpoi-0-lat').innerHTML
        var lat0 = parseFloat(content.substr(content.indexOf(":")+1));

        content = document.getElementById('agpoi-0-lng').innerHTML
        var lng0 = parseFloat(content.substr(content.indexOf(":")+1));

        content = document.getElementById('agpoi-1-lat').innerHTML
        var lat1 = parseFloat(content.substr(content.indexOf(":")+1));

        content = document.getElementById('agpoi-1-lng').innerHTML
        var lng1 = parseFloat(content.substr(content.indexOf(":")+1));

        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng((lat1 + lat0) / 2, (lng1 + lng0) / 2),
          zoom: 18,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

        var polyOptions = {
            strokeColor: '#000000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 3,
            map: map
        };

        poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);

        new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: lat0, lng: lng0},
          map: map,
          icon: ndgIconBase + 'myLogo.png'
        });    

        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: lat1, lng: lng1},
            map: map,
            icon: ndgIconBase + 'myLogo.png'
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
            placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
        });

        var position = {lat: lat0, lng: lng0};

        var path = poly.getPath();
        path.push(position);

        var content;
        for (i = 0; i < countWaypoint; i++) {

            content = document.getElementById("agpoiwaypoints-" + i + "-latitude").value;
            lat = parseFloat(content);

            content = document.getElementById("agpoiwaypoints-" + i + "-longitude").value;
            lng = parseFloat(content);

            position = {lat: lat, lng: lng};

            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map
            });

            path = poly.getPath();
            path.push(position);

        }

        position = {lat: lat1, lng: lng1};

        path = poly.getPath();
        path.push(position);

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'click', placeMarker);

    function placeMarker(position, map) {
        if (clickMarker == 0) {
            clickMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map
            });
        } else {
            clickMarker.setPosition( position );
        }
    }  

    $("body").on("click", ".remove_agpoiwaypoint", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

    });

    $("body").on("click", ".add_agpoiwaypoint", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var path = poly.getPath();
        var position = clickMarker.getPosition();
        path.push(position);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `path = poly.getPath();` you're simply getting an array and assigning it to a variable called `path`.  Then when you do `path.push(position);`  you're merely adding things into that variable... it's not updating the polyline's path.

Instead you then need to update the polyline too, e.g. then you could also do

```
poly.setPath(path);
```

Comment: you are right, this what I just realized after modifying my code to add more features.